# How to use a control from a dll / assembly in XAML?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime, c++-cx

I have a `CustomControl` derived class in a dll (`MyNamespace.UI`). How can I use this control in my main application? I've tried adding a reference to the project and then using a custom XAML namespace to point to my namespace, but it can't find it:

```
<Page ...
    xmlns:ui="using:MyNamespace.UI"
    ...>
<Canvas>
    <ui:MyControl />
</Canvas>
</Page>
```

I get an error:

> The name "MyControl" does not exist in the namespace "using:MyNamespace.UI".

Searching around, I managed to find the following quote:

> The name of the assembly that defines the backing types for a XAML
>   namespace is not specified in the mapping. The logic for which
>   assemblies are available is controlled at the app-definition level and
>   is part of basic app deployment and security principles. Declare any
>   assembly that you want included as a code-definition source for XAML
>   as a dependent assembly in project settings.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/jj150588.aspx

Can someone point me in the direction of the "dependent assembly" setting in the project settings?

**Edit** After making sure the root namespace project setting matched the namespace of my control (`MyNamespace.UI`) I could get the project to compile. But I can't get it to run because I get loads of crashes with the following information:

> WinRT information: Cannot create instance of type 'MyNamespace.UI.MyControl' [Line: 44 Position: 37]

No information on *why* it couldn't make the control though... I stepped through the constructor of `MyControl` and the exception is thrown in `InitializeComponent()`. This is the XAML of my UserControl (`MyControl`):

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="MyNamespace.UI.MyControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Edit 2** I deleted the `Grid` control, built and ran, and it worked, so then I put the `Grid` control back, and it still worked. Very weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the `MyNamespace.UI` assembly has a `RootNamespace` property that matches `MyNamespace.UI`. This property can't be changed in the project settings pages, but you can do it via notepad or equivalent. My `RootNamespace` was set to `UI`, and when I changed it, it started working.